# Actor-isolated property cannot be passed 'inout' to 'async' function call

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'm new (like most everyone, I suppose) to Swift concurrency, and I'm running into a compiler error I don't know what to do with.

```
struct Thing {
  var counter = 0
  mutating func increment() async {
    counter += 1
  }
}

class Controller: UIViewController {
  var thing = Thing()
  
  func mutate() async {
    await thing.increment()
    print(thing.counter)
  }
}

let c = Controller()
Task {
  await c.mutate()
}
```

The first line of the `mutate()` function gives me the following error.
`Actor-isolated property 'thing' cannot be passed 'inout' to 'async' function call`

If I just inherit from `class` instead of `UIViewController` things work fine, but I need the controller here, so I need to figure out how to make this work in that specific context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue comes from `Thing` being a `struct`. A `mutating` func on a struct will assign a new value to the `thing` property on the `Controller`. In order for that to work, `thing` is treated as an `inout` parameter in the call to `thing.increment()`.

If you make thing an `actor` instead of a `struct` then `increment()`won't need to be a `mutating func` and so `thing` won't be treated as an `inout` parameter.

---

A possible workaround is to make a copy of the struct first, then call the mutating func on the copy, then store it back on the property in the controller.

```
func mutate() async {
    var thing = self.thing
    await thing.increment()
    self.thing = thing
    
    print(thing.counter)
}
```

The reason it's an issue is the UIViewControllers are all actors now, so the properties are considered actor isolated. There is a `nonisolated` keyword but it cant be applied to stored properties so it doesn't seem to help here.

If the controller is changed to be an `actor`, the error message changes a bit to say that.

```
error: cannot call mutating async function 'increment()' on actor-isolated property 'thing'
        await thing.increment()
                    ^
```

Comment: changing it from a `struct` to an `actor` (and removing the `mutating` keyword) does in fact get it to compile, but in my non-pared down code that's a pretty hefty refactor. Any ideas how to make it work with `Thing` staying a `struct`?

Comment: I've added a possible workaround in the answer above.